# How to skip rebuild and build for Node.js buildpack

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

When deploying applications to CloudFoundry via the [Node.js buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack)

- npm rebuild
- npm install

are executed every time during staging.

Both operations can take a significant amount of time, especially for applications with complex vendored dependency trees.

My applications do not need any native modules and have all their dependencies vendored.

I search a way to to skip the rebuild and install steps completely during staging.

---

**Edit**: I am aware of the workarounds possible by manipulating `package.json` as suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43919779/3263412).

Other parts of the build system depend on manifest being true to the actual requirements of the applications, so this is not possible for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Cloud Foundry & NodeJS build pack perspective, you cannot skip the [build step](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack/blob/master/src/nodejs/supply/supply.go#L229-L265).  It's going to run with Yarn or with NPM, and [with NPM](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack/blob/master/src/nodejs/npm/npm.go#L21-L52) it'll either run `npm install` or `npm rebuild`.

You have two options:

- [You can vendor your dependencies](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/index.html#vendoring).  If you truly do not have any native dependencies then `rebuild` will basically be a no-op.  If you do have native libraries, which most people do, you can run `npm install` and `cf push` from an Ubuntu Trusty VM or docker container where it can build and vendor even the native libraries.  Again, when you push this will still run `npm rebuild` but if everything is vendored it should basically be a no-op.
- You can fork the NodeJS build pack and change the operations to occur in the order that you want.  This would probably require you to edit the [supply code here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack/blob/master/src/nodejs/supply/supply.go#L248-L257) and add a flag or some way to skip the rebuild.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can add `--ignore-scripts` flag to skip run *pre* and *post* install hooks

`$ npm install --ignore-scripts`

http://blog.npmjs.org/post/141702881055/package-install-scripts-vulnerability

Comment: This deals with some extra work during the `install` and `rebuild` runs, but does not skip the actual commands.

Comment: `npm install` and `npm rebuild`, as stated in the question